clickAction doesnt work for andriod, ios (FCM admin SDK)
I'm trying to make the deep link open when click on the notification. When I click the notification nothing happens.
I'm using nodejs, admin sdk. Also don't understand what on ios to use for deep links (trying to use it all at once, hoping it works)
const payload: MulticastMessage = {
  notification: {
    title,
    body,
  },
  android: {
     notification: {
     clickAction: deepLink,
    },
  },
  apns: {
    payload: {
      aps: {
        category: deepLink,
        data: {
          deep_link: deepLink,
          clickAction: deepLink,
          click_action: deepLink,
          category: deepLink,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  tokens: ['some tokens'],
};

await admin.messaging().sendEachForMulticast(payload);

